# Worst Case Complexity for Pseudocode

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o

We have the following pseudocode  to find the `k`th smallest number in an array.

```
partition(A, begin, end)
   x = A[end]
   i = begin – 1
   for j = begin to end – 1
      if A[j] <= x
         i = i + 1
         swap(A[i], A[j])
         swap(A[i + 1], A[end])
   return i + 1

select(A, begin, end, k)
   m = partition(A, begin, end)
   s1 = m – begin
   s2 = end – m
   s = s1 + s2 + 1
   if s1 >= k
      return select(A, begin, m – 1, k)
   else if s – s2 == k
      return m
   else
      return select(A, m + 1, end, k – s + s2)
```

The `swap()` function just swaps its arguments in a pass by reference way, and it takes constant time.  What might be the worst-case complexity in big-O notation for an array of length `n`?

Comment: Looks like homework. Answering wouldn't be helpful. And would require guessing since this is not a programming language I know.

Comment: What is your analysis so far?

Comment: Hint: every `select()` performs one `partition()` directly.  Some `select()`s recurse.  What is the worst-case cost of `partition()`, and what's the greatest recursion depth that could be reached?

Comment: In worst case, select can recurse  as much as big-end (big minus end) and then it stops. In that case, each select will make partition. May I wrong? The maximum depth is I think N.

Answer (score 0):

Big O Notation is simple because it gives you a general idea of the complexity, based of course on the worst case scenario.

When you partition things it usually means that you have a O log(n), when you have a look it means you have O n, and when you have nested loops you will have O n^x where x is the amount of nested loops, 2 loops means O n^2, three loops means O n^3 and so on. Check the cases you have in your pseudo code and you will get your answer.

I can be wrong but I see that at the worst scenario you are are looping all elements of your A and partitioning all of them because they are all reversed, that would mean O nlog(n) which can be simply put as O log(n).

To better understand algorythms, I recommend this [Standford course](https://www.coursera.org/course/algo)

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I understand from your post is that: I have a for-loop in partition so it is O(n).In addition to this, I have partition, so I have O(logn). What about recursion?

Comment: Recursion is the way you have to loop through your array. 1 Loop means n, 2 loops means 2n, 1 nested loop means n^2